# Train DCGAN with variable input_shape

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network, generative-adversarial-network

I have a dataset with 2d grayscale images, and I want to build a GAN for a problem where the generator isn't my focus. I actually want a very good discriminator able to tell apart real from fake images (generated from the generator).

The thing is, the data I'm working with is not traditional images and the image size is semantic and every pixel is always relevant, so I cannot simply reshape the images. I thought of a solution for the discriminator, in which I'd use adaptative max pooling to get a single output at the end regardless of the input shape, that way if any part of the image appears fake it will return fake.

I have not tested the discriminator the way it is below, its just an example of the change I thought of.

```
class Discriminator(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super(Discriminator, self).__init__()
        self.main = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(1, 64, (4, 4), (2, 2), (1, 1), bias=True),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, True),

            nn.Conv2d(64, 128, (4, 4), (2, 2), (1, 1), bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(128),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, True),

            nn.Conv2d(128, 256, (4, 4), (2, 2), (1, 1), bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(256),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, True),

            nn.Conv2d(256, 512, (4, 4), (2, 2), (1, 1), bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(512),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, True),

            nn.AdaptiveMaxPool2d((1, 1)),
            nn.Flatten(),
            nn.Linear(512, 1),
            nn.Sigmoid()
        )

    def forward(self, x: Tensor) -> Tensor:
        out = self.main(x)
        out = torch.flatten(out, 1)

        return out
```

The thing is, I don't know how to do something similar to the generator, it would make sense for it to generate randomly sized images for the discriminator. How can I achieve that?

For reference, my entire code is below, the way I'm currently running it, with the reshape. And it is working, currently training and with ok partial results, but I really need the change.

```
import torch.nn as nn
from torch import Tensor
import torchvision
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
import os
import torch
import numpy as np
from torch.utils.data import Dataset
import torch.optim as optim
from torch.utils.tensorboard import SummaryWriter
from PIL import Image


class CustomDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, root_dir, transform=None):
        self.root_dir = root_dir
        self.transform = transform
        self.image_filename = os.listdir(root_dir)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.image_filename)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        filename = os.path.join(self.root_dir, self.image_filename[idx])
        image = np.load(filename, allow_pickle=True)
        image = Image.fromarray(image.astype('uint8'))
        if self.transform:
            image = self.transform(image)
        return image


class Discriminator(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super(Discriminator, self).__init__()
        self.main = nn.Sequential(
            # Input is 1 x 64 x 64
            nn.Conv2d(1, 64, (4, 4), (2, 2), (1, 1), bias=True),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, True),
            # State size. 64 x 32 x 32
            nn.Conv2d(64, 128, (4, 4), (2, 2), (1, 1), bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(128),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, True),
            # State size. 128 x 16 x 16
            nn.Conv2d(128, 256, (4, 4), (2, 2), (1, 1), bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(256),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, True),
            # State size. 256 x 8 x 8
            nn.Conv2d(256, 512, (4, 4), (2, 2), (1, 1), bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(512),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, True),
            # State size. 512 x 4 x 4
            nn.AdaptiveMaxPool2d((1, 1)),
            nn.Flatten(),
            nn.Linear(512, 1),
            nn.Sigmoid()
            # nn.Conv2d(512, 1, (4, 4), (1, 1), (0, 0), bias=True),
            # nn.Sigmoid()
        )

    def forward(self, x: Tensor) -> Tensor:
        out = self.main(x)
        out = torch.flatten(out, 1)

        return out


class Generator(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super(Generator, self).__init__()
        self.main = nn.Sequential(
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(100, 512, (4, 4), (1, 1), (0, 0), bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(512),
            nn.ReLU(True),

            nn.ConvTranspose2d(512, 256, (4, 4), (2, 2), (1, 1), bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(256),
            nn.ReLU(True),

            nn.ConvTranspose2d(256, 128, (4, 4), (2, 2), (1, 1), bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(128),
            nn.ReLU(True),

            nn.ConvTranspose2d(128, 64, (4, 4), (2, 2), (1, 1), bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(64),
            nn.ReLU(True),

            nn.ConvTranspose2d(64, 1, (4, 4), (2, 2), (1, 1), bias=True),
            nn.Tanh()
        )

    def forward(self, x: Tensor) -> Tensor:
        return self._forward_impl(x)

    # Support PyTorch.script function.
    def _forward_impl(self, x: Tensor) -> Tensor:
        out = self.main(x)

        return out

    def _initialize_weights(self) -> None:
        for m in self.modules():
            if isinstance(m, nn.Conv2d):
                nn.init.normal_(m.weight, 0.0, 0.02)
                if m.bias is not None:
                    nn.init.constant_(m.bias, 0)
            elif isinstance(m, nn.BatchNorm2d):
                nn.init.normal_(m.weight, 1.0, 0.02)
                if m.bias is not None:
                    nn.init.constant_(m.bias, 0)


def epoch(
        discriminator,
        generator,
        dataloader,
        epoch_n,
        n_epochs,
        device=torch.device("cuda:0"),
        exp_name="exp000",
        criterion=nn.BCELoss(),
        d_lr=0.0002,
        g_lr=0.0002,
):
    writer = SummaryWriter(os.path.join("samples", "logs", exp_name))
    criterion = criterion.to(device)
    d_optimizer = optim.Adam(discriminator.parameters(), d_lr, (0.5, 0.999))
    g_optimizer = optim.Adam(generator.parameters(), g_lr, (0.5, 0.999))
    # Calculate how many iterations there are under epoch.
    batches = len(dataloader)
    # Set two models in training mode.
    discriminator.train()
    generator.train()

    for index, real in enumerate(dataloader):
        # Copy the data to the specified device.
        real = real.to(device)
        label_size = real.size(0)
        # Create label. Set the real sample label to 1, and the fake sample label to 0.
        real_label = torch.full([label_size, 1], 1.0, dtype=real.dtype, device=device)
        fake_label = torch.full([label_size, 1], 0.0, dtype=real.dtype, device=device)
        # Create an image that conforms to the Gaussian distribution.
        noise = torch.randn([label_size, 100, 1, 1], device=device)

        # Initialize the discriminator model gradient.
        discriminator.zero_grad()
        # Calculate the loss of the discriminator model on the real image.
        output = discriminator(real)
        d_loss_real = criterion(output, real_label)
        d_loss_real.backward()
        d_real = output.mean().item()
        # Generate a fake image.
        fake = generator(noise)
        # Calculate the loss of the discriminator model on the fake image.
        output = discriminator(fake.detach())
        d_loss_fake = criterion(output, fake_label)
        d_loss_fake.backward()
        d_fake1 = output.mean().item()
        # Update the weights of the discriminator model.
        d_loss = d_loss_real + d_loss_fake
        d_optimizer.step()

        # Initialize the generator model gradient.
        generator.zero_grad()
        # Calculate the loss of the discriminator model on the fake image.
        output = discriminator(fake)
        # Adversarial loss.
        g_loss = criterion(output, real_label)
        # Update the weights of the generator model.
        g_loss.backward()
        g_optimizer.step()
        d_fake2 = output.mean().item()

        # Write the loss during training into Tensorboard.
        iters = index + epoch_n * batches + 1
        writer.add_scalar("Train_Adversarial/D_Loss", d_loss.item(), iters)
        writer.add_scalar("Train_Adversarial/G_Loss", g_loss.item(), iters)
        writer.add_scalar("Train_Adversarial/D_Real", d_real, iters)
        writer.add_scalar("Train_Adversarial/D_Fake1", d_fake1, iters)
        writer.add_scalar("Train_Adversarial/D_Fake2", d_fake2, iters)
        # Print the loss function every ten iterations and the last iteration in this epoch.
        if (index + 1) % 10 == 0 or (index + 1) == batches:
            print(f"Train stage: adversarial "
                  f"Epoch[{epoch_n + 1:04d}/{n_epochs:04d}]({index + 1:05d}/{batches:05d}) "
                  f"D Loss: {d_loss.item():.6f} G Loss: {g_loss.item():.6f} "
                  f"D(Real): {d_real:.6f} D(Fake1)/D(Fake2): {d_fake1:.6f}/{d_fake2:.6f}.")


def train_model(
        dataset_path,
        image_size,
        experiment_samples_path,
        experiment_results_path,
        batch_size,
        device,
        n_epochs,
        resume_params=None,
):
    discriminator = Discriminator().to(device)
    generator = Generator().to(device)
    # Create a experiment result folder.
    if not os.path.exists(experiment_samples_path):
        os.makedirs(experiment_samples_path)
    if not os.path.exists(experiment_results_path):
        os.makedirs(experiment_results_path)

    # Create an image that conforms to the Gaussian distribution.
    fixed_noise = torch.randn([batch_size, 100, 1, 1], device=device)

    # Set up transformations
    transform = transforms.Compose([
        transforms.Resize([image_size, image_size]),
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.Normalize(0, 0.5)
    ])

    # Create custom dataset
    dataset = CustomDataset(root_dir=dataset_path, transform=transform)

    # Create data loader
    dataloader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True, num_workers=0)

    # Check whether the training progress of the last abnormal end is restored, for example, the power is
    # cut off in the middle of the training.
    if resume_params is not None:
        if resume_params["resume_d_weight"] != "":
            print(f"Resuming Discriminator... {resume_params['resume_d_weight']}")
            discriminator.load_state_dict(torch.load(resume_params["resume_d_weight"]))
        if resume_params["resume_g_weight"] != "":
            print(f"Resuming Generator... {resume_params['resume_g_weight']}")
            generator.load_state_dict(torch.load(resume_params["resume_g_weight"]))

    for epoch_n in range(0, n_epochs):
        # Train each epoch to generate a model.
        epoch(
            discriminator,
            generator,
            dataloader,
            epoch_n,
            n_epochs,
            device=torch.device("cuda:0"),
            exp_name="exp000",
            criterion=nn.BCELoss(),
            d_lr=0.0002,
            g_lr=0.0002
        )
        # Save the weight of the model under epoch.
        torch.save(discriminator.state_dict(), os.path.join(experiment_samples_path, f"d_epoch{epoch_n + 1}.pth"))
        torch.save(generator.state_dict(), os.path.join(experiment_samples_path, f"g_epoch{epoch_n + 1}.pth"))

        # Each epoch validates the model once.
        with torch.no_grad():
            # Switch model to eval mode.
            generator.eval()
            fake = generator(fixed_noise).detach()
            torchvision.utils.save_image(fake, os.path.join(experiment_samples_path, f"epoch_{epoch_n + 1}.bmp"),
                                         normalize=True)

    # Save the weight of the model under the last Epoch in this stage.
    torch.save(discriminator.state_dict(), os.path.join(experiment_results_path, "d-last.pth"))
    torch.save(generator.state_dict(), os.path.join(experiment_results_path, "g-last.pth"))


train_model(
    "../images",
    64,
    "../experimento_1/samples",
    "../experimento_1/results",
    64,
    torch.device("cuda:0"),
    100,
    resume_params=None,
)
```